# Cloudfoundry: Same domain in two orgs

Tags: swisscomdev

Is it possible to use the same domain in two different orgs?

I get following error message while trying to add the domain to a second org

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can share your private domains with any other org by using this CLI command:
`cf share-private-domain ORG DOMAIN`